# LaTeX songs use tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, songs

Is there a way to change the code of the songs package, so that it will add all the songs to the default `tableofcontents` instead that the user has to use the index system?
Something like that didn't work for me:

```
\renewcommand{\songchapter}{\section*}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following redefinition of `\beginsong`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\beginsong[1]{%
  \ifSB@insong\SB@errboo\SB@closeall\fi%
  \ifSB@intersong\SB@errbor\SB@closeall\fi%
  \SB@insongtrue%
  \def\SB@closeall{\endsong}%
  \SB@parsetitles{#1}%
  \global\setbox\SB@songwrites\box\voidb@x%
  \SB@clearbskeys%
  \@ifnextchar[\SB@bskvfmt\SB@@beginsong%
  \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=0}%
  \phantomsection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\numberline{\thesongnum}#1}%
  \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=2}%
}
\makeatother
```

to include the songs as subsections in the ToC, with proper bookmarks and hyperlinks from each entry to the corresponding song.

The complete code, using the files provided by the package authors in its [`downloads section`](http://songs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
% \includeonlysongs{2}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\beginsong[1]{%
  \ifSB@insong\SB@errboo\SB@closeall\fi%
  \ifSB@intersong\SB@errbor\SB@closeall\fi%
  \SB@insongtrue%
  \def\SB@closeall{\endsong}%
  \SB@parsetitles{#1}%
  \global\setbox\SB@songwrites\box\voidb@x%
  \SB@clearbskeys%
  \@ifnextchar[\SB@bskvfmt\SB@@beginsong%
  \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=0}%
  \phantomsection%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\numberline{\thesongnum}#1}%
  \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=2}%
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.1in}
\settowidth{\versenumwidth}{1.\ }
\pagestyle{empty}

\newindex{titleidx}{lbtitle}
\newauthorindex{authidx}{lbauth}
\newscripindex{scripidx}{lbscrip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\songsection{Worship Songs}
\begin{songs}{titleidx,authidx,scripidx}
\input{songs.sbd}
\end{songs}

\showindex{Index of Authors and Composers}{authidx}
\showindex{Index of Scripture}{scripidx}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But unfortunately there is one questions left: How can I remove the doubled bookmarks which are now in the PDF?
Is there a way to disable the setting of bookmars in the songs package or in the default article package?

Comment: @Programmer4000 please see my updated answer; the code at the end of my post will suppress duplicated bookmarks.

Comment: Thank you very much again, you helped me very much!
I'm sorry but there is one little problem left. The hyperlinks in the tableofcontents don't work, they all are going to page 1 instead of the right song page...

Comment: @Programmer4000 You're welcome! In my newly updated answer I've fixed the problem with the hyperlinks. Now they should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much the third time :-) Now everything works like it should be.
You really helped me a lot! Thanks again :D

Comment: Gonzalo, thanks for that code! But I don't understand, why it changed behavior of credits part, e.g: \beginsong{Doxology}[ by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken}, sr={Revelation 5:13}, cr={Public domain.}, index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}] \beginverse* Now it looks on PDF like (the ToC is printed right, but): ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M1eB6.png)

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192160/28900) to this question unfortunately breaks the song package's parser for `\beginsong`.  Here's a different approach that uses the songs package's built-in support for new keyvals:

```
\newcommand\toctitle{}
\newcommand\toclink{}
{\makeatletter\gdef\toclink{\@ifundefined{href}{}{{song\theSB@songsnum-\thesongnum
                                                   .\ifnum\value{section}=0 1\else2\fi}}}}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline
  {\ifnum\value{section}>0sub\fi section}{\numberline\thesongnum#1}{\thepage}\toclink}}
\newsongkey{toc}
  {\def\toctitle{\resettitles\addtotoc\songtitle}}
  {\def\toctitle{\addtotoc{#1}}}
\renewcommand\extendprelude{\showrefs\showauthors\toctitle}
```

This yields the same output as the accepted answer but it

- doesn't break the parser,
- works with or without hyperref loaded,
- works in both chaptered books and sectioned article documents,
- provides a new `\beginsong` keyval `toc={title}` that lets you customize the title that appears for each song in the table of contents, and
- is more likely to remain compatible with future versions of the songs package, since it doesn't redefine any of the package's internal macros.